# proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, virtualhost, vhosts, proxypass

I have added `ProxyPass` in the virtual-host and end up with below error in the error.log file.

> proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a
>   DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included
>   in the configuration using LoadModule.

In the front end I get 500 when I request particular page.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to enable proxy module :

```
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod proxy
```

And restart you Apache server.

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I was trying to get Gitlab to work and had to enable proxy_html as well

Comment: In my case, I needed `proxy_ajp` module. `a2enmod proxy_ajp`

Comment: For me, it was `a2enmod proxy_wstunnel` (to enable WebSockets). I also needed `ProxyPassMatch ^/rtm/ws/(.*)/websocket$ ws://localhost:8080/rtm/ws/$1/websocket` in the configuration file to make sure ws:// won't be remapped to http:// for all requests to /rtm/ws

Comment: `a2enmod proxy_wstunnel` it was! For fixing my SignalR problem with a Apache reversed proxy.